Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Gradle Libs'
I have an existing Flutter project and have resolved several issues so far. However, a new issue has arisen:

Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project
repositories but repository 'Gradle Libs' was added by settings file
'settings.gradle'

This error occurs when I open the project in Android Studio. Interestingly, when I run the project from Visual Studio Code, the error does not appear, and I am able to run the project on an emulator without any issues.
build.gradle (Project:android)
// buildscript {
//     ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
//     repositories {
//         google()
//         jcenter()
//                 mavenCentral() // Add this repository

//     }

//     dependencies {
//         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
//         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

//         // Add the google services classpath
//         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

// //
// //        // Add the Flutter plugin classpath
// //        classpath 'dev.flutter:flutter-gradle-plugin:1.0.0' // Add this line
//     }
// }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
                mavenCentral() // Add this repository

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gradle(project.app)
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" // Ensure this line is correct
}


def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

//  def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
//  if (flutterRoot == null) {
//      throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
//  }

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

// apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
// apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }


    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mbi.MyAduanApp"
        minSdkVersion 30
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs{
        release{
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    lint {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

//flutter {
//    source '../..'
//}

dependencies {
    // implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0'

}

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath
}()

includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.2.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.20" apply false
}

include ":app"

I'm not sure what mistake I have made. I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this problem.
Thank you in advance!
